# Automatically print the next line variable for debugging purpose

Tags: python, debugging, logging, contextmanager

When you are debugging complex code, you sometimes need to transform:

```
def myfunction(self):
    ...
    self.foo.bar = self.baz.bla
```

into

```
def myfunction(self):
    ...
    self.foo.bar = self.baz.bla
    print("myfunction", "self.foo.bar", self.foo.bar)  # add this for debugging purposes
```

**Is there a way (with a decorator or context manager or anything else) to automatically `print` the variable name and the value of the next line of code's assignement (and maybe also the current function)?**

Example:

```
def myfunction(self):
    ...
    with debug:
        self.foo.bar = self.baz.bla
```

would output:

```
 "myfunction self.foo.bar 123"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inspect module:

```
from inspect import currentframe

def f():
    a = 5
    debug_print("a")

def debug_print(var):
    locals = currentframe().f_back.f_locals
    print(f"{var} = {locals[var]}")

f()
```

See also here: [Access parent namespace in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130453/access-parent-namespace-in-python)

I admit, it's only part of what you asked, but maybe a good start.

**Edit**: Ok what about this:

```
from inspect import currentframe, getsourcelines

class A:
    def f(self):
        self.b = 5
        debug_print()
        self.a = A()
        self.a.a = 4
        debug_print()

    @staticmethod
    def g():
        A.c = 5
        debug_print()

def debug_print():
    frame = currentframe().f_back
    locals = frame.f_locals
    globals = frame.f_globals
    source, start = getsourcelines(currentframe().f_back.f_code)
    var_name = source[frame.f_lineno - 1 - start].split("=")[0]
    tokens = var_name.strip().split(".")
    var = locals.get(tokens[0], globals.get(tokens[0], None))
    for t in tokens[1:]:
        var = getattr(var, t)
    print(f"{var_name} = {var}")

a = A()
a.f()
a.g()
```

At least now, it works with member attributes (including `self`), even nested. Also assignment of global variables, such as static attributes to the class.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to be able to do it *without* having to rewrite the variable name. Just `debug_last_line()`. Is this possible?

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! PS: it doesn't work for classes, e.g. `class Test:` `def do(self):` `self.blah = 123` `debug_print()`, but there surely is something in `inspect` to do this!

Comment: Ok, we are getting there. ;-). It's of course still far from universal ... next you ask for is arrays: `field[2] = ...`, but I think I leave that exercise to the reader ;-)