# Access vars() of calling function

Tags: python, debugging

When I debug, I often find it useful to print a variable's name and contents.

```python
a = 5
b = 7
print("a: "+str(a)+"\n b: "+str(b))
```

I want to write a function that achieves this. So far, I have the following function:

```python
def dprint(varslist, *varnames):
    string = [var+": "+str(varslist[var]) for var in varnames]
    print("\n".join(string))
```

An example for its usage is

```python
a = 5
b = 7
dprint(vars(), "a", "b")
```

My question is: is there any way to write `dprint()` such that `vars()` doesn't need to be explicitly passed to it every time it's called? Specifically, is there a way for `dprint()` to access its calling function's `vars()`?

Then, we could rewrite it as

```python
def dprint(*varnames):
    varslist = # magic code that gets vars() from calling function
    string = [var+": "+str(varslist[var]) for var in varnames]
    print("\n".join(string))
```

Comment: In Python, instead of printing the variables, you can use the `breakpoint()` function to debug.

Comment: Take a look at the `inspect` module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access parent namespace in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130453/access-parent-namespace-in-python)

Comment: upvoted as this made me stop and think about how to do it.  @FLAK-ZOSO has the *right* solution for this case though

Comment: Yeah, but it is probably better just to manually pass `vars()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sys._getframe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

> Return a frame object from the call stack. If optional integer depth is given, return the frame object that many calls below the top of the stack. If that is deeper than the call stack, ValueError is raised. The default for depth is zero, returning the frame at the top of the call stack.

Then use `f_locals` to get local vars of `caller`.

```
import sys

def dprint(*varnames):
    caller = sys._getframe(1)  # depth=1
    for var in varnames:
        print(f'{var}: {caller.f_locals.get(var)}')

def foo():
    a = 5
    b = 7
    dprint("a", "b")

foo()
```

Output:

```
a: 5
b: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can debug a program calling the `breakpoint` built-in function.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm using Google Colab, and pdb is quite annoying to use there. (For example, it thinks inputs to the debugger are passwords, so it doesn't show you what you type.)